# Bitbucket webhooks automating releases

Tags: php, git, ssh, bitbucket, webhooks

I am wanting to automate my releases to staging and live enviroments, when I push to my staging branch, I want my staging to server to pull and and update it's codebase.

My repositories live on bitbucket and I am trying to use there webhooks triggering on a repository push.

I have added my public key to my SSH keys on bitbucket, and I can ssh onto my server, and then access bitbubcket via ssh also, however, whenever I do a push my webhook log shows error 401, I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

here is the php code that the webhook is (or is not if it is getting a 401) error,

```
    <?php

/*
Read the raw POST data.
*/
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
if( ! $json)
{
    echo "not json";
    exit;
}

/*
Here we're allowing for the fact that Bitbucket 'POST' hooks and Bitbucket 'Pull Request POST' hooks were developed at different times and
send the data in different ways. Here's an explanation http://tinyurl.com/m96th4j
*/
if( $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] == 'application/json')
{
    $payload = json_decode($json);
}
else 
{
    $payload = json_decode(urldecode(substr($json, 8)));
}

if(is_null($payload))
{
    exit;
}

/*
Here we just sift through the payload and see if we have recieved a pull request merge (and the branch is 'release-candidate') OR
we have received a commit (and the branch is 'release-candidate')
*/
if((isset($payload->pullrequest_merged) && $payload->pullrequest_merged->destination->branch->name == 'dev-master') || (isset($payload->commits) && $payload->commits[0]->branch == 'dev-master'))
{
    /*
    Run the command to navigate to the website
    root and perform the git pull
    */
    echo "hello";
    system('cd /var/www/vhosts/popsapp.com/dev.popsapp.com && git pull');
}
```

Am i doing anything wrong? If there a way to find why I am being rejected access to my bitbucket when pull from my dev server?